Predicates and functions
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d");

    strings.stream()
            .filter(s -> test(s, "temp"))
            .map(s -> transform(s, "temp"))
            .filter(s -> anotherTest())
            .map(s -> anotherTransform())
            .count();
}

public static boolean test(String s1, String s2) {
    return s1.equals(s2);
}

public static String transform(String s1, String s2) {
    return s1 + s2;
}

public static boolean anotherTest() {
    return true;
}

public static String anotherTransform() {
    return "temp";
}

Considering the code given above, I am confused as to how I am able to pass test method that returns a boolean but accepts two arguments for filter in place of a Predicate and transform method for map in place of a Function. It also works for methods with no arguments like anotherTest and anotherTransform and it's really confusing.
Does only the return type matter for predicates and functions and not the number of arguments?

As long as the result of the method call satisfies the expected return type, that should be all you need to worry about.

You don't "pass ‘test’ method", you pass a lambda calling the method. The lambda itself has one argument and fills it in the call to the two arguments method (s).

I understand when people are confused about method references where the arguments are implicit, but this example literally shows that the caller looks like test(s, "temp"). What can be confusing about an invocation of a target method with two arguments naming exactly two arguments (s and "temp")?

The filter expects a predicate taking one string in input and returning a boolean value, and with s -> test(s, "temp") you are defining exactly that. Another way to do it could be using a class implementing the predicate like the example below:
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d");

        strings.stream()
           .filter(new MyPredicate())
           .count();
    }
}

class MyPredicate implements Predicate<String> {  
    public boolean test(String s) { 
        return ClassContainingStaticTestMethod.test(s, "temp");
    }
}

class ClassContainingStaticTestMethod{
    public static boolean test(String s1, String s2){
        return s1.equals(s2);
    }
}

Instead of using a class you are defining it "on the fly" by using a lambda

EDIT: to address a few more doubts: you DON'T pass the method, you pass the lambda which is (in this case) a way of implementing the Predicate. You could write anything inside the lambda's body (call a method taking zero, one, two, or a thousand arguments, or don't calling a method at all!) as long as you stay compliant with the Predicate's test method signature. In your case, in the lambda you are CALLING the static method defined within the same class you are defining the lambda.

how does it work when we pass methods with no arguments?

You aren’t passing any such method. You are calling it from inside the lambda, but it is the lambda itself that is being passed here, and it does satisfy the required signature. Read the answer again, and the comment by @daniu.

The point is, it wouldn't work to pass a method with no arguments. The signatures of say, filter specifies the type of function it needs (that is, one that takes an item and returns a bool). Admittedly, function types might be a bit hard to read in Java (as compared with, say, Kotlin). In any case, the compiler will complain if you pass a function that has the wrong type.

@ndc85430 That's incorrect, you are not passing a method, you are passing the lambda. See the comment of user207421 above. If the lambda internally uses a method without arguments (meaning it won't use the argument, s in this example) is up to you and that's fine.

@ndc85430 the parameters of the lambda expression are to the left of the ->. I don’t see where this is hard to read, especially compared to Kotlin where you can omit the parameters and the ->, having a syntax indistinguishable from an ordinary code block.


I am confused as to how I am able to pass ‘test’ method that returns a
boolean but accepts 2 arguments for filter in place of a Predicate...

In your code, this is the Predicate: s -> test(s, "temp"). You can also write this as: s -> s.equals("temp").

... and ‘transform’ method for map in place of a Function.

In your code, this is the Function: s -> transform(s, "temp"). This can also be written as: s -> s + "temp".
So, your code can be simply written as:
strings.stream()
    .filter(s -> s.equals("a")) // using "a", instead of "temp" to see a result
    .map(s -> s + "temp")
    .filter(s -> true)
    .map(s -> "temp")
    //.count();
    .forEach(System.out::println); // using this to print a result, instead of count()

s -> s.equals("a"), what is this? This is a lambda expression for the Predicate. The predicate is a function that returns a boolean. java.util.function.Predicate<T> is a functional interface, has a single functional method test(T), and this method returns a boolean.
And, the predicate can be written and used as follows, for example:
As an anonymous inner class:
Predicate<String> p1 = new Predicate<>() {
                            @Override public boolean test(String s) {
                                return s.equals("a");
                            }
                       };

Or, as a lambda expression:
Predicate<String> p1a = s -> s.equals("a");

And, the code to use the predicate:
strings.stream()
    .filter(p1) // or p1a or s -> s.equals("a")
    .forEach(System.out::println); // this prints "a"

Similarly, the function for the Stream#map method:
Function<String, String> f1 = new Function<>() {
                                   @Override public String apply(String s) {
                                       return s + "temp";
                                   }
                               };
// or, as a lambda      
Function<String, String> f1a = s -> s + "temp";

// Use the function     
strings.stream()
    .filter(p1)
    .map(f1)  // or f1a or s -> s + "temp"
    .forEach(System.out::println); // this prints "atemp"



It also works for methods with no arguments like anotherTest and
anotherTransform and its really confusing.

anotherTest and anotherTransform are methods created by you, and they do not represent a Predicate or a Function.

Does only the return type matter for predicates and function and not
the number of arguments?

Both the return type and the arguments matter (you will see compile time errors if not so). You can try using the example code from above and verify.

References:

Predicate
Function
Lambdas
Functional Interfaces


You can also refer these topics in Java Language Specification (Java SE 8): Lambda Expressions and Functional Interfaces. Java Streams, Lambdas and Functional Interfaces were introduced with Java SE 8 - hence the functional programming capabilities.

Your comment should be in your answer.
